# App apk size exceed 100mb. How to upload it on PlayStore?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

App apk size around 145 MB. It Contains 9-10 gif Images around 100 MB.So,I  can't upload app on google play store.

**So I am trying to implement app bundle by using this link**:-
https://medium.com/@AndreSand/android-app-bundle-96ac16b36875

app bundle makes successful with .aab extension but its size is not less and when I try to upload it on google play store it gives an error that some apk file size has more than 100 MB.

Comment: Did you use proguard ?

Comment: App bundles are definitely the right approach but may not solve your problem. Try to use a comprised version of GIF or cache them from the network. Bundling this much large file into APK may not sound good.

Comment: You can use expansion files https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files

Comment: @CagriYalcin yes,I used proguard

Answer (score 4):

> Google Play currently requires that your ***APK file be no more than 100MB***. For most applications, this is plenty of space for all the application's code and assets. However, some apps need more space for high-fidelity graphics, media files, or other large assets. Previously, if your app exceeded 100MB, you had to host and download the additional resources yourself when the user opens the app. Hosting and serving the extra files can be costly, and the user experience is often less than ideal. To make this process easier for you and more pleasant for users, Google Play allows you to attach two large expansion files that supplement your APK.

Read [**`APK Expansion Files`**](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files).

**FYI**

> The new app publishing format, the [**`Android App Bundle`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/), is a more efficient way to build and release your app. The Android App Bundle lets you more easily deliver a great experience in a smaller app size.

Comment: yes,I am trying this link to make app bundle but it could not upload on play store due to more size

Comment: @MagentoMobile Reduce image size.

Comment: @MagentoMobile Read https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya  make app bundle using dynamic module  follow below link
https://medium.com/mindorks/dynamic-feature-modules-the-future-4bee124c0f1

When upload on play store got below error:-
ne or more of the auto-generated multi-APKs exceeds the maximum allowed size of 100 MB.

Your app bundle contains the following configurations where the initial install would exceed the maximum size of 100 MB: ARM64_V8A + XHDPI, ARM64_V8A + XXHDPI, ARM64_V8A + XXXHDPI, ARM64_V8A + TVDPI so on
Please suggest what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

will be more better to upload low size APk otherwise user will never download app from play store. if you have large images or gifs and you don't have server then you can use firebase storege where you can easily store your files and fetch . where you can upload your file and get images paths .