# My App is 256 Mb in size and i want to publish it to playstore but the maximum size is 100 mb to upload what to do now

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

i created an app that consist 500 files and many assets files and the size of apk will goes more than 200 mb but the accepted size by play store is 100 mb not please tell me how i will decrease the size or upload it on playstore

Comment: You can follow this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944679/app-apk-size-exceed-100mb-how-to-upload-it-on-playstore or remove those files and load it later after user open the app instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App apk size exceed 100mb. How to upload it on PlayStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944679/app-apk-size-exceed-100mb-how-to-upload-it-on-playstore)

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67816628/flutter-how-to-know-the-size-of-a-flutter-plugin/67817238#67817238), to see which files are eating most of the size. Also try to compress assets and not bundle them, but download them on the first app start to slim down the binary size

Comment: not able to build the apk as it shows package_info error that sdk was not found

Comment: is there any way to manually use sha key to generate keystore file